# Shortcut for moving to the beginning of an indented block in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3

I am writing the body of a loop which is indented as

```
>(place that I want my cursor to go to)
for i in range(1,10): 
     ...
     (several lines of code)
     ...
     >(place that my cursor is at)
```

Is there a shortcut in Sublime Text 3 that will take my cursor from anywhere in the indented block to the place where the indented block begins or ends?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with **`Selection → Expand Selection to Paragraph`**?